from autoware_auto_msgs.msg import BoundingBoxArray ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autoware_auto_msgs' OSSDC SIM with Autoware.Auto and RViz
I am currently working on integrating the OSSDC simulator with Autoware.Auto and RViz. However, I am encountering a couple of issues that I need some help,
I am trying to import BoundingBoxArray from autoware_auto_msgs, but I keep getting the following error:
"from autoware_auto_msgs.msg import BoundingBoxArray ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autoware_auto_msgs'"
However, I do not see any data from the simulator in RViz. Is there a specific configuration or topic I should be subscribing to? Could there be any missing steps in setting up the communication between RViz and the OSSDC simulator?
Any help or guidance on these issues would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

please do not post pictures of text ... post the text
